# How to keep a youtube embedded video Centered when on full screen mode

Tags: html, css, youtube

I am successful in centering the youtube embedded video, but the problem is, when I go to full-screen mode, the video position is out of the screen because of `transform:translate(-50%)` property

Here is my code:

```
<div class="videoWrapper">
<iframe class="trailervideo" width="560" height="315" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TDwJDRbSYbw" frameborder="0" 
allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
.videoWrapper {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
padding-top: 25px;
height: 0;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
position: absolute;
max-width:560px;
max-height:315px;
width: 95%;
height: 95%;
left:50%;
transform:translate(-50%);
}
```

[Link of fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v547jw00/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I go to full-screen mode, the video position is out of the screen because of transform:translate(-50%) property

Well then let’s just throw that away, and use auto margins to center the element instead:

```
.videoWrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    max-width:560px;
    max-height:315px;
    width: 95%;
    height: 95%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin: auto;
}
```